# brown leafs on tomato

Tags: leaves, tomatoes

I've transplanted a tomato plant into a bigger pot recently. I noticed that it has brown leafs. One big, in the picture and a few small spots. 
What is this? This plants grows indoors and is already producing fruit.
[image]

**UPDATE ON PLANT:**
The plant is doing just fine. Brown stuff turned into veru bright brown, and didn't grow or anything. Same with the bottom spot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the rest of the plant is healthy and it is producing fruit, I would not worry about it.  Leaves do try out or turn brown so I personally would not be concerned but keep a close eye to see if other symptoms appear.  I would also pluck off that leaf.  I am assuming you are watering and fertilizing regularly.